# Flutter Dio post an object with array

Tags: http, flutter, dart, dio

I am trying to post a request to api with an object as"

```
var params =  {
    "item": "itemx",
    "options": [1,2,3],
    };
    print(params);
    try {
      Response response = await _dio.post(getAddToCartURL,
          queryParameters: params,
          options: Options(headers: {
            HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: "application/json",
          }));

    } catch (error, stackTrace) {
      print("Exception occurred: $error  stackTrace: $stackTrace");
      return false;
    }
```

Dio sends the object as :

```
POST /api/add-to-cart/?item=itemx&options%5B%5D=1&options%5B%5D=2&options%5B%5D=3
```

in which the api recognize it as a bad request.

what is wrong that i am doing here? I have even tried the list as [ "1","2","3"], it is the same.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It all depends on how the API expects it. I would suggest trying to encode it as JSON.

```
var params =  {
  "item": "itemx",
  "options": jsonEncode([1,2,3]),
};
```

But sending complex data in query parameters isn't always that easy. Since you are using POST anyway, maybe send a JSON object as body instead of using query parameters.

```
var params =  {
  "item": "itemx",
  "options": [1,2,3],
}; 
...
Response response = await _dio.post(getAddToCartURL,
  options: Options(headers: {
    HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: "application/json",
  }),
  data: jsonEncode(params),
);
```

Comment: thanks for the hint, it actually worked. I thought sending params as an object is enough but as i tried sending authentication params to the same api. Thanks

Comment: cant we send this type of array in get method?

Comment: GET requests don't have a body and the data has to be put in URL parameters. In general that can be tricky, but it's definitely possible. The first code snippet suggests a way of using GET, the second snippet is for using POST which would generally be the better option but you need to change this on server side as well

Comment: good example...

Comment: Hi there, I tried this sample code in dio^4.0.6, but I couldn't receive data in my server.
Other way I tried @AmirahmadAdibi 's answer and it works.
Is this caused by `dio` version?

Comment: That would be rather unlikely. I assume your API might be expecting form data instead of json

Answer (score 0):

another example for any one might be helpful , posting fomr data

```
            var formData = FormData.fromMap({
              'data': json.encode(
                  {'salt': salt, 'placeholder': 'palceholder', 
                  'method_name': 'app_details'})
            });

            var response = await dio.post(
              BaseUrl,
              data: formData,
            );
```

the final result of your request is this

[image]