# Dio (for flutter) - How to send an array int to queryParameters?

Tags: flutter, http, dart, request, dio

I use dio in my Flutter app. I have get request. I need add int array to request param.
This is an example:

```
api/my?param1=6&param2=5&exclude_id=[7364, 7365, 7366]
```

This is my code in dart:

```
 List<int> ids = [7364, 7365, 7366]
 String jsonIds = jsonEncode(ids); 
 final params = <String, dynamic>{
    'param1': 6,
    'param2': 5,
    "exclude_id": jsonIds
  };
 final response = await _dio.get('/api/my', queryParameters: params);
```

but it comes to the server as (from the text log):

```
   api/my?param1=25\u0026param2=6\u0026exclude_id=%5B7172%2C8%2C7150%2C7156%2C3848%2C7212%2C7168%2C15%2C24%2C4102%2C1032%5D
```

how do I add this parameter to the request correctly? any advice?

Comment: Have you tried to convert the list to string?

Comment: Answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61542834/flutter-dio-post-an-object-with-array regularly!

Answer (score 3):

If you know that the server is able to handle the `int`s in the form: `"1234,2345,3456"`, you can simply join them before you pass them to dio:

```
 List<int> ids = [7364, 7365, 7366]
 final params = <String, dynamic>{
    'param1': 6,
    'param2': 5,
    "exclude_id": ids.join(','),  // "7364,7365,7366"
  };
 final response = await _dio.get('/api/my', queryParameters: params);
```

Note, the correct answer depends on what format your server expects. If it is a 3rd part server, try looking at their docs.

Also, HTTP URLs cannot contain (among other things) whitespace, but the output of `jsonEncode` may include whitespace. Generally it is not common to see JSON-encoded data in URL parameters, it is much more common in request/response bodies